# Touch Pad doesen't work on linux mint 20.1 xcfe in an Aspire ES1-520 V1.06

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

so I'm using a Aspire ES1-520 V1.06 with Linux Mint 20.1 xcfe, and suddenly when I turned on my laptop the touchpad didn't work and I couldn't find it in the dmesg, i have tried a bounch of things thath i found on internet but any of them make a difference one of them that I think it's important was that I  the file

> /ect/default/grub
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 nosplash irqpoll"
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.elantech_smbus=0"

If someone could help me i would be ver greatful

Comment: Could you add the output of `xinput list` to your question.

Comment: Don’t worry it suddenly start working again today don’t understand how if i didn’t change anything